# Jquery .empty() first 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

The jquery method `.empty()` removes all child nodes of an element.
How can I specify using `.empty()` to remove the first 2-3 or the last 2-3 elements?

docs:

> This method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements,
>   but also any text within the set of matched elements.

Example:

```
<div id="foo">
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div id="two"></div>
   <div id="three"></div>
   <div id="four"></div>
   <div id="five"></div>
   <div id="six"></div>
</div>

$('#foo').empty()
```

would "return":

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

how to make it "return" for example (in this case the last four are "emptied")

```
<div id="foo">
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#three').remove();

Comment: Is what you want to remove always a (set of) elements, as it is in your example?

Comment: Find the elements you want and use `.remove()`

Comment: yes I want to put a calculated integer for example so that it dynamically removes a set of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to remove always a (set of) elements, as it is in your example, just use [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to identify the children to remove and remove them with [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). (In the below, I'll ignore the fact the ones you want to remove have IDs as that's clearly just for illustration.)

#### Remove the first four:

```
$("#foo").children().slice(0, 4).remove();
```

Example:

```js
$("#foo").children().slice(0, 4).remove();
```

```html
<div id="foo">
   <div id="one">one</div>
   <div id="two">two</div>
   <div id="three">three</div>
   <div id="four">four</div>
   <div id="five">five</div>
   <div id="six">six</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Remove the last four:

```
$("#foo").children().slice(-4).remove();
```

Example:

```js
$("#foo").children().slice(-4).remove();
```

```html
<div id="foo">
   <div id="one">one</div>
   <div id="two">two</div>
   <div id="three">three</div>
   <div id="four">four</div>
   <div id="five">five</div>
   <div id="six">six</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `slice()` or `:gt()` to get the required elements from the collection, then `remove()` them. Try this:

```js
$('#foo div').slice(2).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
   <div id="one">one</div>
   <div id="two">two</div>
   <div id="three">three</div>
   <div id="four">four</div>
   <div id="five">five</div>
   <div id="six">six</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it does, as a jQuery object is never null.

Comment: @utdev `.empty()` removes all the child nodes in the element. What you wanted is to iterate through each child node select those that you want to remove, which is done by `.remove()`. Calling `.empty()` on the child nodes will not remove them, which is what you want.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ye I know, I always wait a few hours, to give other people a chance to answer.

Comment: You're unlikely to get any more answers once your question is off the front page of the 'newest' list. If there's anything you feel is missing or that I could improve on, let me know

Answer (score 2):

```js
//$('#foo div:gt(1)').empty();
$('#foo div:gt(1)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
   <div id="one">1</div>
   <div id="two">2</div>
   <div id="three">3</div>
   <div id="four">4</div>
   <div id="five">5</div>
   <div id="six">6</div>
</div>
```

Use [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

With [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

> Description: Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i think OP wants to remove child only ?

Comment: i suggest remove now which remove the matched element in selector.